# Python : assign a column using lambda with if else

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a date column in a dataframe, and I'd like to create another column that I call peak_day. If the day name of the day in the date column is a weekend (Sat or Sun), it will return false, else True.
I got the code to work....but not sure what I'm doing wrong in the "bad" code. I could just move on....but I'm trying to really understand what the code does wrong and be a better coder:)

Here's the code that works:

```
pk_day = lambda pkday : (df['Date'].dt.strftime('%a') == 'Sat' ) | (df['Date'].dt.strftime('%a') == 'Sun')
```

Here's the line that doesn't work - but I thought it's just a more explicit version of the first one:

```
pk_day = lambda pkday : False if  df[ (df['Date'].dt.strftime('%a') == 'Sat' ) | (df['Date'].dt.strftime('%a') == 'Sun') ] else  True
```

Here's the error this line generates:

```
The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I also tried a slight variation with the df and square brackets to enclose the statement:

```
pk_day = lambda pkday : False if  (df['Date'].dt.strftime('%a') == 'Sat' ) | (df['Date'].dt.strftime('%a') == 'Sun') else True
```

and I get the same error as the previous line. It looks like there could be two sets of boolean values being generated by False and True results explicitly in the code and that causes it to fail? What is causing this?

Would appreciate the guidance! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is:

```
df["pk_day"] = df["Date"].dt.weekday.lt(5)
```

Now, for why your second statement does not work. You're using:

```
df[(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%a')=='Sat')|(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%a')=='Sun')]
```

This returns the rows in the DataFrame where the day is a weekend. Hence, it is *not* boolean.
You could use:

```
lambda pkday:False if ((df['Date'].dt.strftime('%a')=='Sat')|(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%a')=='Sun')) else True
```

Your last statement works without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple, the following will do the job.

```
pk_day = lambda pkday : df['Date'].dt.strftime('%a') in ('Sat','Sun')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `assign` method to create new column by including lambda. The advantage of `assign` method is you can create multiple columns within same assign method & is more efficient.

```
df = df.assign(pk_day=df['Date'].dt.strftime('%a').isin(['Sat', 'Sun']))
```